# @RequestParam defaultvalue does not accept enum value as a default value

Tags: spring-mvc, enums, annotations

I am using spring rest controller.

Here is the code.

```
@RequestParam(value = "status", required = false, defaultValue = StatusEnum.STATUS.toString())
```

If i use enum as a defaultValue i am getting The value for annotation attribute RequestParam.defaultValue must be a constant expression.

As per my understanding it should accept enum as a default value.

Please advice.

Comment: A method call is not a "constant expression".

Comment: A "constant expression" is something that can be resolved at compile time. Like a static final field, a string or a number.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since it has to be a String, and it has to be a constant expression, your only real option here is to use the value that will work for `Enum.valueOf()`, since that's how this is eventually resolved.

Specifically, yours should read

```
@RequestParam(value = "status", required = false, defaultValue = "STATUS")
```

Assuming, of course, that `"STATUS"` is the string value for `StatusEnum.STATUS`.

Comment: Else can use StatusEnum.STATUS.name()

Comment: @user2344797 only constant expressions are allowed.

Comment: @Dineshmohan name() does not work either. I wonder why though... cuae it has to evaluate to a string at compile time and all enum are constants by default. If anyone could explain... it woudl be great!!

Answer (score 2):

A work around to avoid strings in different location is to use something like that

```
public enum StatusEnum {
    STATUS();
    
    public class Names {
       public static final String STATUS = "STATUS";
    }
    
 }
```

And in the query param

```
@RequestParam(value = "status", required = false, defaultValue = StatusEnum.Names.STATUS)
```