# @RequestParam and mapping enum

Tags: java, spring-mvc, enums

I have a problem with enum as `@RequestParam`. In the method `getRooms` there are two enums: `Sort.Direction` and `SourceFunding`. The `Sort.Direction` is the build-in Spring enum, and it convert from String to Enum perfectly:

```
http://address:port/all?sortDirection=ASC => OK
http://address:port/all?sortDirection=DESC => OK
```

but when I call

```
http://address:port/all?sourceFunding=PUBLIC_INSURANCE => ALWAYS ERROR.
```

I have read and tested:

[Spring's @RequestParam with Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774427/springs-requestparam-with-enum)

[Spring boot able to accept Enum as Request parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55372117/spring-boot-able-to-accept-enum-as-request-parameter)

[Enums as Request Parameters in Spring Boot Rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56233187/enums-as-request-parameters-in-spring-boot-rest)

[How to convert multiple values to enum in RequestParm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67210546/how-to-convert-multiple-values-to-enum-in-requestparm)

[@RequestParam defaultvalue does not accept enum value as a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554538/requestparam-defaultvalue-does-not-accept-enum-value-as-a-default-value)

[Accept and parse integer for Enum type query parameter in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69541088/accept-and-parse-integer-for-enum-type-query-parameter-in-java)

[@RequestParam with a list of parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63281231/requestparam-with-a-list-of-parameters)

and many others with no effect. Also I have tried to emulate Sort.Direction in my enum.

****** the code *******

The error:
{
"timestamp": "2022-07-15T15:53:27.371+00:00",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'xxx.xxxxx.Leo.booking.SourceFunding'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam xxx.xxxxx.Leo.booking.SourceFunding] for value ''PUBLIC_INSURANCE''; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant xxx.xxxxx.Leo.booking.SourceFunding.'PUBLIC_INSURANCE'",
"path": "/room/all"
}

and also could be

Parameter value [PRIVATE_INSURANCE] did not match expected type [xxx.xxxxx.Leo.booking.SourceFunding (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [PRIVATE_INSURANCE] did not match expected type [xxx.xxxxx.Leo.booking.SourceFunding (n/a)]

The controller:

```
    @GetMapping(path = "/all")
    public Page<Room> getRooms(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") Integer pageNumber,
                               @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") Integer pageSize,
                               @RequestParam(defaultValue = "id") String sortBy,
                               @RequestParam(defaultValue = "ASC") Sort.Direction sortDirection,
                               @RequestParam(required = false) Long departmentId,
                               @RequestParam(required = false) Long hospitalId,
                               @RequestParam(required = false) SourceFunding sourceFunding
                               ) {...}
```

The enum:

```
public enum SourceFunding {
    PUBLIC_INSURANCE,
    PRIVATE_INSURANCE,
    PAID_BY_CITIZENS,
    PAID_BY_COMPANY,
    CHARITY,
    COLLECTIVE_FUNDING_FSS,
    OTHER,
    NONE;
}
```

update 1 - that's crazy...

```
SourceFunding.valueOf(sourceFundingString); => Error 'No enum constant ...'

log.info("!! {}", Arrays.toString(SourceFunding.values())); => Return all enum's fields
```

Comment: `@RequestParam(defaultValue = "PUBLIC_INSURANCE") SourceFunding sourceFunding` can you try using defaultValue & check what it gives you?

Comment: @AshishPatil tried - the same error.

Comment: How you are calling your webservice? via curl or any tool?

Comment: @AshishPatil via Postman

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me while using postman, your query parameter input is not getting correct value. Error shows it has single quote in your input `'PUBLIC_INSURANCE'`.

Spring uses `Enum.valueOf(string)` to evaluate queryParam value. If we use `'PUBLIC_INSURANCE'` ,it will not find any corresponding enum.

Can you try to log your input request in `tests` section of postman via `console.log(pm.request.url.query)` & check if your input is proper or not.

Console log in postman can be visible by clicking `View`->`Show Postman Console`

Comment: from the postman concole ```GET http://localhost:8082/room/all?sourceFunding=NONE ``` get the same error: Parameter value [NONE] did not match expected type [Leo.booking.SourceFunding (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [NONE] did not match expected type [Leo.booking.SourceFunding (n/a)]

Comment: no no, you are not getting my point, in `tests` section, just use `console.log(pm.request.url.query)`  & click on  View->Show Postman Console, & hit your request normally, you should see what are parameters you are passing in console.log

Comment: I just want to check if you are passing any special character as  a part of your input. if that is case, your code will fail

Comment: in tests section - you mean Postman section or intellij idea tests?

Comment: ```curl http://localhost:8082/room/all?sourceFunding=NONE``` get the same error

Comment: @Alex,  what headers it is accepting at moment?

Comment: I think the input is correct, for example ```http://localhost:8082/room/all?sortDirection=ASC``` works well, this is the same postmann and the same method of the same controller

Comment: I am trying to create absolutely new project to replicate the error

Comment: maybe this is not my day - https://start.spring.io/ - this cannot start a new project because cannot see maven ....... attempt #12 .... cannot create any java class in new project....

Comment: this is definitely not my day - no light at home :)

Comment: you can try tomorrow, no worries .. :-), let me know in case anything further required from my end.